# EntityFramework PowerTools ReverseEngineer no mapping POCO classes

Tags: entity-framework, models, poco

I'm trying to use Entity Framework PowerTools Reverse Engineer from an existing database in SQL server. It says successful and the context file is generated, however no Mapping folder with the poco classes is created.

I try to run this on a MVC4 project in VS2012, can there be a problem that its not allowed to add this to the Models folder?

Comment: Maybe. Run VS as administrator to find out. Or maybe there is a models folder but it's not added to the project for some reason. (So it's only visible in file explorer).

Comment: I run it as admin, i've tried to reinstall EF and EF-powertools, still no mapping folder generated. Tried it on a regular c# project aswell, same problem. No files in file explorer either. What can i do?

Comment: Add breakpoint to the Mapping.tt and try to debug it. Here is an article explaining how to debug T4 templates: http://www.olegsych.com/2008/09/t4-tutorial-debugging-code-generation-files/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure every table in your database have primary key setup.